# I think I need to change the format of how the date is stored

Tags: date, sqlite, field, reformat

I have a field in a SQLite3 database stored as a date field.
Not thinking, I entered the date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and now none of the date functions will work.

Is there a simple way I can convert the dates to the proper format so I can perform searches that work correctly?

Comment: I typically use int(10) and throw in a good ol' unix timestamp --- but if you throw us some code to illustrate what you're talking about a bit better, I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

If the fields have a fixed length, you can extract them with a few simple [substr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) calls:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET DateColumn = substr(DateColumn, 7, 4) || '-' ||
                 substr(DateColumn, 1, 2) || '-' ||
                 substr(DateColumn, 4, 2);
```